# loading events from a database into a calendar primefaces

Tags: java, html, jsf, primefaces, java-ee-6

i'm having a trouble in loading some dates into a calendar, using the "schedule" component in primefaces. Here is what my client.xhtml look like :

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">

    <body>

        <ui:composition template="./PlanningTemplate.xhtml">

            <ui:define name="top">
                top
            </ui:define>

            <ui:define name="content">
            <p:schedule id="schedule" value="#{scheduleController.eventModel}" widgetVar="myschedule">  
                 <p:ajax event="dateSelect" listener="#{scheduleController.onDateSelect}"  oncomplete="eventDialog.show()" />  
                 <p:ajax event="eventSelect" listener="#{scheduleController.onEventSelect}" oncomplete="eventDialog.show()" />  
                 <p:ajax event="eventMove" listener="#{scheduleController.onEventMove}"  />  
                 <p:ajax event="eventResize" listener="#{scheduleController.onEventResize}"  />  

            </p:schedule>
                <p:dialog widgetVar="eventDialog" header="Event Details" showEffect="clip" hideEffect="clip">  
        <h:panelGrid id="eventDetails" columns="2">  
            <h:outputLabel for="title" value="Title:" />  
            <p:inputText id="title" value="#{scheduleController.event.title}" required="true"/>  

            <h:outputLabel for="from" value="From:" />  
            <p:inputMask id="from" value="#{scheduleController.event.startDate}" mask="99/99/9999">  
                <f:convertDateTime pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" />  
            </p:inputMask>  

            <h:outputLabel for="to" value="To:" />  
            <p:inputMask id="to" value="#{scheduleController.event.endDate}" mask="99/99/9999">  
                <f:convertDateTime pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" />  
            </p:inputMask>  




        </h:panelGrid>  
    </p:dialog> 
            </ui:define>




            <ui:define name="bottom">
                bottom
            </ui:define>

        </ui:composition>

    </body>
</html>
```

The baking been looks like this :

```
@Named(value = "scheduleController")
@SessionScoped
public class scheduleController implements Serializable {
    @PersistenceContext(unitName="MajanTelepointagePU")
    EntityManager em;
    private ScheduleModel eventModel;
    private ScheduleEvent event = new DefaultScheduleEvent() {};

    List<Intervention> listOfAllInterventions = new ArrayList<Intervention>();


    public scheduleController(){
        eventModel = new DefaultScheduleModel();
        // Load here the events into the eventModel via the method aventmodel.addEvent(title,startDate,endDate)

        //get the list of all interventions
        listOfAllInterventions = em.createNamedQuery("Intervention.findAll").getResultList();
        for(Intervention i : listOfAllInterventions){
            eventModel.addEvent(new DefaultScheduleEvent(i.getNotesGeneral(),i.getHeureDebut(),i.getHeureFin()));

        }



    }
    public ScheduleModel getEventModel() {
        return eventModel;
    }

    public void setEventModel(ScheduleModel eventModel) {
        this.eventModel = eventModel;
    }

    public ScheduleEvent getEvent() {
        return event;
    }

    public void setEvent(ScheduleEvent event) {
        this.event = event;
    }


    public void addEvent(ActionEvent actionEvent) {  
        if(event.getId() == null) { 
            eventModel.addEvent(event);  }
        else { 
            eventModel.updateEvent(event);  }

        event = new DefaultScheduleEvent();  
    }  

    public void onEventSelect(SelectEvent selectEvent) {  
        event = (ScheduleEvent) selectEvent.getObject();  
    }  

    public void onDateSelect(SelectEvent selectEvent) {  
        event = new DefaultScheduleEvent("", (Date) selectEvent.getObject(), (Date) selectEvent.getObject());  
    }  

    public void onEventMove(ScheduleEntryMoveEvent event) {  
        FacesMessage message = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "Event moved", "Day delta:" + event.getDayDelta() + ", Minute delta:" + event.getMinuteDelta());  

        addMessage(message);  
    }  

    public void onEventResize(ScheduleEntryResizeEvent event) {  
        FacesMessage message = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "Event resized", "Day delta:" + event.getDayDelta() + ", Minute delta:" + event.getMinuteDelta());  

        addMessage(message);  
    }  

    private void addMessage(FacesMessage message) {  
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, message);  
    }  


}
```

but the client.xhtml is not running, and here is the full stacktrace of the exception :

```
com.google.common.collect.ComputationException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.google.common.collect.ComputingConcurrentHashMap$ComputingMapAdapter.get(ComputingConcurrentHashMap.java:397)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ClientProxyProvider.getClientProxy(ClientProxyProvider.java:102)
    at org.jboss.weld.el.AbstractWeldELResolver.lookup(AbstractWeldELResolver.java:115)
    at org.jboss.weld.el.AbstractWeldELResolver.getValue(AbstractWeldELResolver.java:96)
    at javax.el.CompositeELResolver.getValue(CompositeELResolver.java:188)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:176)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:203)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstIdentifier.getValue(AstIdentifier.java:103)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:179)
    at com.sun.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:224)
    at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldValueExpression.getValue(WeldValueExpression.java:50)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:109)
    at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:194)
    at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:182)
    at javax.faces.component.UIOutput.getValue(UIOutput.java:169)
    at org.primefaces.util.ComponentUtils.getValueToRender(ComponentUtils.java:64)
    at org.primefaces.component.inputtext.InputTextRenderer.encodeMarkup(InputTextRenderer.java:77)
    at org.primefaces.component.inputtext.InputTextRenderer.encodeEnd(InputTextRenderer.java:51)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:875)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeRecursive(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:312)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.GridRenderer.renderRow(GridRenderer.java:185)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.GridRenderer.encodeChildren(GridRenderer.java:129)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:845)
    at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChild(CoreRenderer.java:59)
    at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChildren(CoreRenderer.java:47)
    at org.primefaces.component.dialog.DialogRenderer.encodeContent(DialogRenderer.java:172)
    at org.primefaces.component.dialog.DialogRenderer.encodeMarkup(DialogRenderer.java:101)
    at org.primefaces.component.dialog.DialogRenderer.encodeEnd(DialogRenderer.java:43)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:875)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1764)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1760)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1760)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:402)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:131)
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:288)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:121)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:594)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1550)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:281)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:161)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:331)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$AdapterCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:317)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:860)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:757)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1056)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:229)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflectionAccess.runAsInstantiation(SecureReflectionAccess.java:186)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflections.newInstance(SecureReflections.java:341)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ProxyFactory.create(ProxyFactory.java:242)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ClientProxyProvider.createClientProxy(ClientProxyProvider.java:87)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ClientProxyProvider.access$000(ClientProxyProvider.java:43)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ClientProxyProvider$1.apply(ClientProxyProvider.java:53)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ClientProxyProvider$1.apply(ClientProxyProvider.java:46)
    at com.google.common.collect.ComputingConcurrentHashMap$ComputingValueReference.compute(ComputingConcurrentHashMap.java:355)
    at com.google.common.collect.ComputingConcurrentHashMap$ComputingSegment.compute(ComputingConcurrentHashMap.java:184)
    at com.google.common.collect.ComputingConcurrentHashMap$ComputingSegment.getOrCompute(ComputingConcurrentHashMap.java:153)
    at com.google.common.collect.ComputingConcurrentHashMap.getOrCompute(ComputingConcurrentHashMap.java:69)
    at com.google.common.collect.ComputingConcurrentHashMap$ComputingMapAdapter.get(ComputingConcurrentHashMap.java:393)
    ... 62 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at MajanTelepointage.BB.scheduleController.<init>(scheduleController.java:48)
    at MajanTelepointage.BB.scheduleController$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.<init>(scheduleController$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.java)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:372)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:325)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflections$16.work(SecureReflections.java:344)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflectionAccess.run(SecureReflectionAccess.java:52)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflectionAccess.runAsInstantiation(SecureReflectionAccess.java:173)
    ... 73 more
```

More exactly, the error is referencing the following line :

```
 listOfAllInterventions = em.createNamedQuery("Intervention.findAll").getResultList();
```

Thanks for Help :)

Answer (score 0):

Did you understand the stack trace? It's telling that `em` is `null` inside the constructor. You can also just say that so instead of showing the stack trace. Exceptions from `java.lang` package are rather trivial.

In any way, injected dependencies are indeed not available in the constructor. It's technically not possible to set the value of an instance field before the instance is constructed. If you'd like to work on the injected dependencies directly after instance's construction, then you should be using a `@PostConstruct` annotated method.

Replace

```
public scheduleController(){
```

by

```
@PostConstruct
public void init() {
```

And `em` will be available in there.

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, [Java naming conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-135099.html#367) dictate that class names must start with uppercase. Please work on that as well.

Comment: hi BalusC :) is this means that i have to decalre my entity manager inside the init() method, i'v done this, the schedule client is running, and it displayed the schedule, but no event is loaded !?

Comment: You don't need to declare the `em` in the `init()` method. You've already declared it as an instance variable with `@PersistenceContext` annotation. Just keep it as is. You don't need to change anything else than provided in the above answer. If you declare it inside the `init()` method, the container won't be able to inject it. As to the new problem of apparently retrieving no results, that is a completely different problem than the one currently being asked. Press `Ask Question` to ask a new question about that.

Comment: By the way, I have after all the impression that you completely misunderstood the meaning of "declaring". I suggest to go through a basic Java tutorial to get the concepts/terms straight.

Comment: my last comment concerns your first one, for your second one, I think I know that classes fields should be declared first, and not inside any of the methods of the class, I think my english is the cause of that :/